# Laravel 6 redis session not storing to redis when using database number other than zero

Tags: php, laravel, session, redis

Using laravel 6.8, php7.4. I'm using redis sessions, inside database.php it looks like this:

```
'session' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
    ],
```

And then in .env:

```
REDIS_DB=0
```

Everything seems to be working fine with this setup, I can see session stored in redis and it matches `\Session::getId()`. Problem is when I update REDIS_DB param in .env to something else, example `REDIS_DB=1`, there is no session stored in redis, i.e. I can get the session id using `\Session::getId()` but it's not present when I do `print_r(Redis::keys('*')`

Any help or hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you connect with `redis-cli` and execute `select 1` and then `keys *` ?

Comment: I can see the \Session::getId() in the key list! What does it mean? Laravel doesn't select the appropriate index somehow?

Comment: Added a brief explanation for what is going on and alternative solutions.

Comment: why you want to update RADIS_DB = 1?

Comment: @Ersoy thanks for your help. Looks like doing Redis::select(env('REDIS_DB')); did the trick! Please post an answer if you want.

Comment: @realife i added as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default redis and session may use different redis, or different database even in the same redis. When you set database `1` to session connection, it will always read, write from database `1`. But since your redis's `default` database connection is set to `0`, you can't get your session keys from by just calling `Redis::keys('*')` since the data is on the two different databases.

There are two ways to solve it;

- Setting to database name while querying;

```
Redis::select(1);
return Redis::keys('*');
```

- Updating the default redis config by setting `REDIS_DB` to `1`.